# No shadow on custom model

Tags: unity

I have custom low poly model ,the thing is it is not receiving shadows.

Unity's default plane do receive the shadow but not my low poly plane.

Here is image that demonstrate more,
[image]

Comment: Recommend you check which shader is applied to your plane. Certain shaders optimize by skipping lights and shadows.

Comment: Hi thanks, both model have same shaders i.e., Standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things you might want to check:

1. Your custom plane has a mesh renderer with "Receive shadows" checked.
2. Your second cube has "cast shadows" checked
3. Your light's culling mask.

Comment: thanks for replay, problem just got solved by setting Norlamls to "Calculate" in Model's inspector view

Comment: you should post that as an answer and accept it, for the benefit of future people with this problem

Answer (score 0):

From description and image the first thing I'd check are normals. First check if normals are *imported* by selecting your model file (Model panel). If so, in the **Normals** section try to change from **Import** to **Calculate**. Alternatively, check in your 3D editing software if the normals are properly distributed; if not, fix and reimport. It could also be a geometry problem; make sure you don't have overlapping faces or misplaced vertices. (What happens if you import a sphere from the same software and with the same format?)

Answer (score 0):

There is another possiblity.

One use a custom shader with no `ShadowCaster` pass, while doesn't have a fallback to "Diffuse" or other Unity built in shaders which have the `ShadowCaster` pass.

Or someone don't like the fallback and comment it out, no aware of the shadow issue.